# Bundle install fails on perftools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm getting errors when installing perftools using bundle install. I get:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
(I'm about to compile google-perftools.. this will definitely take a while)
  -- tar zpxvf gperftools-2.0.tar.gz
  -- patch -p1 < ../../../patches/perftools.patch
  -- patch -p1 < ../../../patches/perftools-notests.patch
  -- patch -p1 < ../../../patches/perftools-pprof.patch
  -- patch -p1 < ../../../patches/perftools-gc.patch
  -- patch -p1 < ../../../patches/perftools-debug.patch
  -- patch -p1 < ../../../patches/perftools-objects.patch
  -- patch -p1 < ../../../patches/perftools-frames.patch
  -- patch -p1 < ../../../patches/perftools-realtime.patch
  -- patch -p1 < ../../../patches/perftools-pause.patch
  -- sed -i -e 's,SpinLock,ISpinLock,g' src/*.cc src/*.h src/base/*.cc src/base/*.h
  -- ./configure --disable-heap-profiler --disable-heap-checker --disable-debugalloc --disable-shared
  -- make
checking for method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for method.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for method.h... yes
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... no


***************************************************************************************
****************** Debugger::RubyCoreSource::create_makefile FAILED *******************
***************************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/j9/ghqqd20n13q5kjn2w0btg18m0000gn/T/bundler20140505-18890-1n58ssn/perftools.rb-2.0.1/gems/perftools.rb-2.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/j9/ghqqd20n13q5kjn2w0btg18m0000gn/T/bundler20140505-18890-1n58ssn/perftools.rb-2.0.1/gems/perftools.rb-2.0.1/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing perftools.rb (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install perftools.rb -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

However, when I do `gem install perftools.rb -v '2.0.1'` it builds and installs correctly.

I am using ruby 2.0.0-p353, with rbenv 0.4.0. I'm using gcc version 4.2.1

I tried bundle installing with ruby 1.9.3 as well and get the same error. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: It doesn't seem it's a Ruby problem, but rather a perftools compilation problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the mkmf.log file that the error mentions? Was there any other error about missing files in the error output? If it installs correctly without bundler, maybe bundler is operating in a different environment (looking at .bundle/config if it exists and comparing ruby -v and bundle exec ruby -v may be helpful, too)?

I ran into something similar trying to set up a project that used this version of the gem with the same ruby version on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc v4.8.2, bundler version 1.7.4. Oddly enough running bundle install again after it fails worked for me, but I haven't had a chance to dig deeper to figure out why. :/